# Why is my wordpress site redirecting to the hosting company site?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, web-hosting

I have a site which am building. Suddenly, any link I click like to go to a new page takes me to the hosting company site. What could be the cause?

I have checked my cpanel for errors. Everything seems fine.

I hosted on Awardspace

Answer (score 0):

If only now just started, try disable plugins or themes. if it works, one of them is causing the problem.
That's assuming your website is live.